# Setting completekey=None removes up-arrow functionality

Tags: python, python-3.x, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to write a small REPL using the [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) library in Python. One of the features that it provides is automatic tab completion, which I do not want.

Luckily, the docs mention "If completekey is not None and readline is available, command completion is done automatically." So I set `completekey=None` when I instantiated my `cmd.Cmd` subclass, which worked.

However, the main functionality of the `cmd` module, the use of `readline` which gives support for up-arrow history, was also disabled, and now I'm back to `^[[A`'s.

Why is this happening, and is there a solution?

Comment: It likely happens because when `completekey=None`, the `readline` module is never loaded (see [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/cmd.py). You may be able to work around by subclassing `cmd.Cmd`, overriding either the `cmdloop` or overriding `complete` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readline` module is only imported if `completekey` has a non-None value. It looks like the only way to use `readline` and disable completion is to specify a do-nothing completer.

```
class CmdSubclass(Cmd):
    # Other configuration
    # ...

    def complete(self, *args):
        pass
```

Comment: this does prevent one from entering raw tabs, but I guess I can live with that.

Comment: You can also set `completekey` to something else that you don't need to use as often.